# How do get real value of latitude and longitude from GpsDirectory?

Tags: java, geocoding

I am writing a Java program which actually read all meta data of an image (ex. latitude, longitude and datetime). Following is the my sample code which i am running.

```
public static void findLatLong(File jpg){
    try {
        Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(jpg);    
        if (metadata.containsDirectory(GpsDirectory.class)) {
            GpsDirectory gpsDir =(GpsDirectory)metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
            GpsDescriptor gpsDesc = new GpsDescriptor(gpsDir);
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + gpsDesc.getGpsLatitudeDescription());
            System.out.println("Longitude : " + gpsDesc.getGpsLongitudeDescription());
            System.out.println("Date : " + gpsDesc.getGpsTimeStampDescription());
            System.out.println("Minute  : " + gpsDesc.getDegreesMinutesSecondsDescription());
        }else{
        //  System.out.println("----- Did not find GPS Information-------------for file " + jpg.getName() );
        }

    } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output: -
Latitude: 21.0° 8.0' 22.999999999998693"
Longitude : 79.0° 3.0' 12.999999999994998"
Date : 14:16:30 UTC
Minute  : 21.0° 8.0' 22.999999999998693", 79.0° 3.0' 12.999999999994998"

I suppose this all are degree format. Can anybody point me how do get real value for latitude and longitude. And also to get proper date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using metadata-extractor >= 2.6.0 you can use new [`com.drew.lang.GeoLocation`](http://javadoc.metadata-extractor.googlecode.com/git/2.7.0/com/drew/lang/GeoLocation.html) class ([changelog](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/wiki/ChangeLog#2.6.0)).

```
GpsDirectory gpsDirectory = metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class);
GeoLocation location = gpsDirectory.getGeoLocation();
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

If not, this is what is being done in the [new class sources](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/source/browse/Source/com/drew/lang/GeoLocation.java):

```
   /**
     * Converts DMS (degrees-minutes-seconds) rational values, as given 
     * in {@link com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory},
     * into a single value in degrees, as a double.
     */
    @Nullable
    public static Double degreesMinutesSecondsToDecimal(
            @NotNull final Rational degs, @NotNull final Rational mins, 
            @NotNull final Rational secs, final boolean isNegative)  {

        double decimal = Math.abs(degs.doubleValue())
                + mins.doubleValue() / 60.0d
                + secs.doubleValue() / 3600.0d;

        if (Double.isNaN(decimal))
            return null;

        if (isNegative)
            decimal *= -1;

        return decimal;
    }
```

where the method parameters come from:

```
Rational[] latitudes = getRationalArray(GpsDirectory.TAG_LATITUDE);
Rational[] longitudes = getRationalArray(GpsDirectory.TAG_LONGITUDE);
String latitudeRef = getString(GpsDirectory.TAG_LATITUDE_REF);
String longitudeRef = getString(GpsDirectory.TAG_LONGITUDE_REF);
```

Comment: I am getting date like "Date : 15:45:26 UTC". Is there any method which gives date in standard format like yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z?

Comment: I tried to use  gpsDirectory.getDate(GpsDirectory.TAG_GPS_DATE_STAMP), but it returns null